# Cannot start embedded TomCat server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I wrote a SpringBoot project and tested it perfectly with Postman. However I want to change server address `localhost:8080` to `192.168.42.21`. But when I run project it gives me this error:

```
    org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:212) ~[spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:297) ~[spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163) ~[spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
        at com.mangement.demo.RestaurntManagementApplication.main(RestaurntManagementApplication.java:13) [classes/:na]
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: standardService.connector.startFailed
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:265) ~[spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:196) ~[spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
        ... 10 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1066) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
        ... 12 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.initServerSocket(NioEndpoint.java:228) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:211) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1141) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:592) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1063) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
        ... 14 common frames omitted
```

Can someone help me to fix this error? Thanks

Comment: How did you change localhost:8080 to 192.168.42.21, where is config you used?

Comment: You can use the property `server.port=8084` to set the port adddress for your springboot application. Is that what you wanted to do ?

Comment: My config is in `application.properites` file. I add 2 line of code `server.address = 192.168.x.x` and `server.port = 19000`

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can't set `server.address=192.168.x.x`, on https://docs.spring.io/, `server.address` is "Network address to which the server should bind.". This doesn't mean you just need two line of config to run your application on `192.168.42.21:19000` instead of `localhost:8080`

On your case, if you want another computer on LAN network access to your application, you only need using url: `http://ip:port` with `ip` is ip of your computer you runed spring boot and `port` is port of your application

If you want to public your application to Internet, you need one static ip and you need config port forwarding on your network